# Exercise 8.15 Brezis - Interpolation inequality

Tags: functional-analysis, inequality, sobolev-spaces, interpolation, interpolation-theory

I have a problem with this exercise (see the text in the following link).

[Interpolation like inequality ,Question from Brezis' book exercise 8.15](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2689105/interpolation-like-inequality-question-from-brezis-book-exercise-8-15#comment10389064_2689105)

The link practically solves it. Only one last step is missing, namely proving the inequality when $u(0)\neq 0$. Brezis suggests using $\zeta u$. I tried to do the calculations, but there is something that doesn't add up for me. Since $\zeta(t)=1$ for $t\in[1/2,1]$, for this interval, I have the desired inequality. But how do I handle $[0,1/2)$?

Comment: Apply the inequality to $\tilde u(t) = u(1-t)$.